# Using lambda to format my string based on the number of Floors

Tags: c#, lambda

```
public string KeyWithFloor =>
            $"{Name} - {Floor} Floor";
```

This works 90% of the time if there is more than 1 Floor. However if there is 1 Floor. I want to only display the name

```
public string KeyWithFloor =>
            $"{Name}"
```

I am not sure how to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

------------------ UPDATE

I used

```
public string KeyWithFloor =>
    Floors == 1
    ? $"{Name}"
    : $"{Name} - {Floor} Floor";
```

and it's removing the First Floor from buildings that are multi floors.
I just need it to be removed from a building if it's only 1 floor

Comment: `=> (Floor == 1 ? Name : $"{Name} - {Floor} Floor");`

Answer (score 1):

```
public string KeyWithFloor =>
    Floors == 1
    ? $"{Name}"
    : $"{Name} - {Floor} Floor";
```

Or:

```
public string KeyWithFloor => $"{Name}{(Floors == 1 ? $"- {Floor} Floor" : "")}";
```

Comment: In the 2nd one, I think it's cleaner to use `=> Name + (Floors == 1 ? $" - {Floor} Floor" : "");`.

Comment: @41686d6564 Yes maybe, although concatenation creates a redundant string.

Comment: Okay. I tried the first one and the problem is if I have a building with 3 floors. I want to have it say Building - 1st Floor, Building -2 Floor, Building - 3 Floor. However if I have a building with a single floor, I just want the building name.

Comment: The solution above removes 1 Floor if the building has more than 1 floor

Comment: @softwareisfun Can you add your class to the question? `Floors` was a placeholder for determining the number of floors in the building, not the current floor.

Comment: Yes it’s for determine the floors. The app is supposed to allow a customer to select the floor so the max building occupancy and floor occupancy isn’t reached. (COVID-19) but I just want it to look nice when they are selecting a building that only has 1 floor.